# Setting my C# form as a child to another application

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child, z-order

I'm currently developing a form application which works as an overlay to another program (Skype). Right now, I'm using TopMost = true, but that's a pretty bad solution.

I have a handle to the Skype window, as well as a handle to my own window. How do I make my program fulfill the following three statements:
1. It has to disappear if Skype is minimized
2. It has to appear above Skype
3. It has to appear behind any other application which is above Skype

Above and behind relates to z-order.

I'm currently using the SetWindowLong function, but I cant get the desired results.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, HandleRef dwNewLong);

SetWindowLong(
    new HandleRef(child, child.Handle),
     -8, // GWL_HWNDPARENT
     new HandleRef(owner, owner.Handle));
```

For #1, my application continually checks if the dimensions of Skype has changed, so I could simply also check if the window is no longer visible. However, I'm completely at loss with #2 and #3.

Thanks in advance.
Kloar